# Measurement of the "Straightened" length of a path

Tags: bezier-curves, measurement

So, I'm having a bit of trouble with scaling. An object I'm making involves the use of a path to form a curved surface, but I need the resulting curve to be within about 1% of an exact length.

[image: Curve]

So, if I were to have, say, this curve here that I made for purposes of this question... is there an efficient way to tell how long the black part would be if you straightened it out to a perfect line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Animation Nodes addon there is a node to do just that: [Get Spline Length](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/spline/get_spline_length.html).

The [example usage](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/spline/get_spline_length.html#examples-of-usage) is what you need.

Comment: Oh wow. That's SO much easier than I'd anticipated. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

The [Curve Tools addon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/add_curve/curve_tools.html) can also measure the length of a curve and may be easier to use if you're not already familiar with the Animation Nodes addon.

To measure the length of a curve using Curve Tools:

1. Enable the Curve Tools addon (under *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*).
2. Select the curve object.
3. Press <kbd>N</kbd> to show the sidebar and click the *Edit* tab.
4. Expand the *Curve Tools* panel, expand the *One Curve* subpanel, and click *Calc Length*.

Comment: That also works quite well, and honestly, getting a sidebar is a fair bit more accessible and clearcut than having to open a node tree to get a single number.

Comment: seems to not works for nurbs curves in 2.8?

Answer (score 4):

1. make a plane
2. go to array modifier
3. change fit type to ' fit curve '
4. select the curve
5. scale the plane to 0.001, smaller you scale the plane more accurate the curve length
6. check length in sidebar by pressing 'N'

Comment: [Also my preferred method for getting length in global coords.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159719/15543)