# What's the easiest way to measure a nonlinear path?

Tags: measurement

The measure tool is handy for measuring the distance between two points, but I would like to measure the distance along the surface of a mesh.

What I'm doing currently is just measuring several small segments to sort of approximate the curve and then adding them all up manually, but that's incredibly tedious. I had hoped the measure tool could do multi-segment lines, which would at least take care of having to manually add up the individual segments, but it doesn't seem to have that function.

Comment: can you do something with UV if you add seams to unwrap without distorting too much. Finding the actual shortest route over a 3D mesh is non-trivial (without actually thinking about the algorithm or checking to see if someone's already done it for blender!)

Comment: Might be [related...](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116670/measurement-of-the-straightened-length-of-a-path)