# How to measure the arc of an object

Tags: objects, measurement

I'm going to modeling a my computer's mouse But I do not know how to measure the actual size in the blender **The problem is that I do not know how to measure the arc**
[image]

I want to finally print it on a 3D printer

Comment: You don't know how to measure the arc in real life or inside blender ?

Comment: @Gorgious in real life

Comment: It's not a regular arc by the look of it anyway. I'd use a reference image of it in Blender and then use proportional editing modelling against the image.

Comment: @John Eason You recommend using this image in the blender?

Comment: For the side view, yes, unless you have proper blueprint images of it. You'll also need one end-on (maybe for front **and** back) and from the top of course. Depends how detailed you want to get if you're 3D printing it later.

Comment: See the answer here, you can open your image as Reference in Blender, create a curve that follows the shape, then calculate the length with the Curve Tools addon (second answer): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116670/measurement-of-the-straightened-length-of-a-path#:~:text=Enable%20the%20Curve%20Tools%20addon,subpanel%2C%20and%20click%20Calc%20Length

Comment: Take a piece of paper, make it bend around the mouse, straighten it up, mark it with a pen, measure it with a ruler. No need for blender for that ?